# SQL for pairing rows by value of field

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table:

```
create table transaction_log (
  id serial, 
  operation_type character varying(36),
  date timestamp with time zone,
  sum   double precision,
  user_id integer,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

It keeps two type of operations: `block` and `unblock` for multiple users (contragent_id) and lots (lot_id) and datetime field of `operation`.

- One user can have multiple block and unblocked operations
- Records with block operation can have a one unblock operation after.
- Blocks and unblocks are sequencual. There must be a block for user and next block could be only after unblock operation happened.
- Unblock date and time could be the same as block. It means blocked and instantly unblocked.
- One user could have multiple sequences of block and unblock operations on a mixed timeline.
- id is unique

For example:

```
id, sum, operation_type, date, user_id
1, 5900, blocked, 2018-01-05 11:00, 1
2, 3500, blocked, 2018-01-08 12:00, 2
3, 5900, unblock, 2018-02-11 09:00, 1
4, 1000, blocked, 2018-01-09 05:00, 3
5, 3500, unblock, 2018-01-24 19:00, 2
```

So I need to get SQL to fetch all block operations with date of corresponding unblock operation, if it exists. E.g.: block_ID, sum, blocked_date, unblock_date. So, from example data I need to get:
For example:

```
block_ID, sum, blocked_date, unblock_date
1, 5900, 2018-01-05 11:00, 2018-02-11 09:00
2, 3500, 2018-01-08 12:00, 2018-01-24 19:00
4, 1000, blocked, 2018-01-09 05:00, null
```

I suppose that I need a WITH statement for this, but I can't get it how to match records correctly.

Any help appreciated.

BTW Postgres 9.4

Comment: sample data and expected output more fruitful

Comment: Sample data with SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/68b3c/9

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that we are running 9.4

Comment: So for a user there cannot be two blocked records following each other; there must be an unblock record inbetween. Same vice versa: there cannot be two unblock records following each other; there must be a blocked record inbetween. You say that two events can happen at exactly the same timestamp. Would this always mean "blocked and instantly unblocked" or could it also mean "unblocked and instantly blocked again"?

Comment: Yes. Updated descripion. two events can happen at exactly the same timestamp means "blocked and instantly unblocked"

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way

```
with block as
     (
    select * from transactions
    where operation='blocked'
    ),
    unblock as 
    (
    select * from transactions
    where operation='unblock'
    )
    select block.id as block_ID, block.sum,
    block.date, unblock.date from block
    left join unblock on block.user_id=unblock.user_id
```

Comment: This would not work. Id is unique for each record in table, not for block-unblock pair. I added examples to question.

Comment: @Zhlobopotam does it helps?

Comment: Example works, but with more real date - nope http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/99da1/7 (here block operation with same lot_id and contragent_id must be matched with next unblock record with same lot_id and contragent_id

Comment: @Zhlobopotam could you please give me  expected result  according to your real data your

Comment: For the example data block operation with id 34788321 must have unblock date from record with id 34788322. Record 34795864 will have date from 34795866 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent, you are merely looking for the minimum unblock date following a block date. You can get this in a subquery in your `SELECT` clause:

```
select user_id, sum, date as block,
(
  select min(ub.date)
  from blocktable ub
  where ub.operation_type = 'unblock'
  and ub.user_id = b.user_id
  and ub.date >= b.date
) as unblock
from blocktable b
where operation_type = 'blocked';
```

Or in the `FROM` clause with a lateral join:

```
select b.user_id, b.sum, b.date as block, ub.unblock
from blocktable b
left join lateral
(
  select min(ub.date) as unblock
  from blocktable ub
  where ub.operation_type = 'unblock'
  and ub.user_id = b.user_id
  and ub.date >= b.date
) b
where operation_type = 'blocked';
```

With a lateral join can even get the whole row:

```
select *
from blocktable b
left join lateral
(
  select *
  from blocktable ub
  where ub.operation_type = 'unblock'
  and ub.user_id = b.user_id
  and ub.date >= b.date
  order by ub.date
  fetch first 1 row only
) as unblock
where operation_type = 'blocked';
```

Another option to get the single date would be `LEAD`:

```
select user_id, sum, block, unblock
from
(
  select
    user_id,
    sum,
    date as block,
    lead(date) over (partition by user_id order by date, operation_type) as unblock,
    operation_type
  from mytable
) block_and_unblock
where operation_type = 'blocked';
```

If you want a query that works great even in case of inconsistencies (especially two blocked or two unblocked records following each other), you may have to select the data sequentially, i.e. in a recursive query or with an app.